# Issue of Checking Email

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem when I want to check Email if it's WRONG or not I use this method but I have anything with Red color as message I try to enter a wrong email but I have any message in output email.

The file of Register.php

```
if(!empty($_POST['email_check']))
{
    $email=$_POST['email_check'];

    exit();

    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        echo'<br/> Mail Error !';
        exit();
    }
  }
```

The function of AJAX(I put ALERT(data) but I have anything):

```
     <script>    
        /* Jquery AND AJAX */ 
         $(document).ready(function(){ 

 $("#email").keyup(function(){ 
            check_email();  
        });
              function check_email(){
              $.ajax({
              type: "post",
              url: "register.php",
              data: {

         email_check: $("#email").val()
          },

              success : function(data){
               alert (data);
              if(data.trim() == 'success'){



              $("#output_email").html(' ');

              }
                  else{
               $("#output_email").css("color","red").html(data);
              }
              }

              });
              }
    });
```

In the same file of ajax 
the HTML code:

```
  <div class="form-group">

  <label for="email" class="col-sm-5 control-label">EMAIL :</label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">

      <input type="Email" id="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Your Email " required>
               <small id="output_email"></small>
    </div>
```

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Why are used keyup event, because when your key is up your ajax call is fire and you got a response immediately.So you have to change your event like click event (submit or button).

Comment: Also the same probleme and now i try to put this code just for test but i have anything in out $("#email").keyup(function(){ 
            alert("True")  
               
        }); I haven't the alert Message

Comment: Can you please describe what you want exactly,So i would like explain better

Comment: after my test with alert("...") My probleme now that i haven't contact with id="email" in my control of TEXTBOX and my event key up I haven't the alert message "True" I don't know where is the probleme

Comment: the probleme  is here he don't call email id                    <div class="form-group">
   <label  for="email"  class="col-sm-5 control-label"> Email  :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <input  id="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Your Email " required>
         <small id="output_email" ></small>
    </div>
            
   
      </div>

Comment: So what you want to back in your ajax success call.

Comment: Ohh men you really dont know how to explain your question.

Comment: Now i want if i try to writ in control of email the message of alert appair if this is solve all my code will be solved ;)

Comment: the problem is in reading function he can't read my function check_email()

Comment: Okay just remove exit(); function in your register.php file and change event keyup to focusout in your ajax call

Comment: Ohh, can i send you hold demo if you want

Comment: ok Send me and if you want give me your adresse mail to contact you for more explain you my probleme

Comment: Send me your email address

Comment: I try to write as you have told me but the same probleme

Comment: don.khalil@hotmail.fr

Comment: Can you got my mail i sent you an email?.

Comment: Yes i am going to open it

Comment: If you help this please tick my answer in stackoverflaw

Comment: your code is code is the same that what i put but i don't know why it's doesn't work in my home do you have teamviewer :D

Comment: Sorry i m not able to connect with team-viewer, and what you got any error or ourput?.

Comment: NO I have any error with your code but when i try to put that on my code he don't work :( but me i don't have only this code i have many code in my page :D you see

Comment: do you want that i send you all my project ? by email

Comment: Not for now but i will met you monday

Comment: I send you now for not forget and you take your time on monday ok ?